# UnsupportedCommandException while executing seleium script with firefox 59.0.3 (64-bit) gecko driver 0.15

Tags: selenium-firefoxdriver

I am a beginner in Selenium. This is my code I am executing. I am using Selenium-Java-3.3.1 version, Firefox 59.0.3 (64-bit) and gecko driver 0.15 version
    package selenium_test;

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;

public class TestClass {

WebDriver driver;

public void invokeBrowser() {

    try {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\GEGDC\\KT00475829\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.15.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.get("https://stg2-magic.health.ge.com:13007/enovia/common/emxNavigator.jsp");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    TestClass myObj = new TestClass();
    myObj.invokeBrowser();
}


}
```

Below is my error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: timeouts
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '5234b32', time: '2017-03-10 
09:00:17 -0800'
System info: host: 'TMIC-PCS2200', ip: '3.235.34.200', os.name: 'Windows 7', 
os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
```

Please help me in solving my error.